# how to repeat local notification after 14 days in iOS 8 & 9

Tags: ios, objective-c

The code to register for notifications is:

```
   UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

And the code to schedule the notification:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[self setNotificationTypesAllowed];
if (notification)
{
    if (allowNotif)
    {
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        if ( [statusString isEqualToString:@"daily"]) {
            notification.fireDate = _timePick.date;

                notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
        }else if ( [statusString isEqualToString:@"weekly"]) {
            notification.fireDate = _timePick.date;

                notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;

        }else if ( [statusString isEqualToString:@"fortnightly"]) {
            notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*14];;
            notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;

            //notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitYear;
        }else{
                notification.repeatInterval = 0;
        }
    }
    if (allowsAlert)
    {
        notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Do you really want to send message to %@",name];
    }
    if (allowsBadge)
    {

        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    }
    if (allowsSound)
    {
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    }
    notification.alertAction = @"Yes";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showSMS) name:@"showSMS" object:nil];

    // this will schedule the notification to fire at the fire date
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

I am able to repeat local notification daily & weekly but it is not repeating fortnightly ,please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes as @Nikos suggested, try below code:

1. Cancel UILocalNotification.

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
   ```
2. Schedule local notification

   ```
   UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
   notification.userInfo = @{@"notification_identifier":@"After14Days"};
   notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24*14)];
   notification.alertBody = @"Text to display";
   notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
   ```

If you have any doubt then let me know.

Comment: the above code will not repeat the notification after every 14 days if the user  does not open the app for 30 day.

Comment: but the question demands for repeat the notification after every 14 day not once.

Comment: @RamaniAshish yes you are right I forgot to add one line for repeat notification. I edited my answer you can see now.

Answer (score 0):

To set a notification to fire every 14 days you have to create 26 separate UILocalNotifications with the `repeatInterval` set to `NSYearCalendarUnit` (the repeat interval must be set to a calendar unit, and there is no 14 days CalendarUnit in iOS).

Another way to handle it is to cancel the `UILocalNotification` in the `didReceiveLocalNotification` method and schedule a new one there for after 14 days. This method though assumes that the user interacts with the notification, otherwise the next one will never get scheduled.